# Archiving React Native project fails with PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code. Node in error message doesn't match installed version

Tags: react-native

The project was archiving fine before, but after installing yarn globally for a different project, it started failing with the following error:

> Node found at: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.9.0/bin/node
>
> $PROJECT_DIRECTORY/ios/Pods/../../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/../../scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.sh:
> line 83: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.9.0/bin/node: No such file or directory
>
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

If I run `node --version` in my terminal, I get back v19.0.1.

I tried running the commands below to try and relink node but I get the same build errors.

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/node
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```

Answer (score 11):

Figured out my problem. When running `pod install` for the first time, an `.xcode.env.local` was auto-generated in the `/ios` folder with `$NODE_BINARY=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/18.9.0/bin/node`. I updated it to the node version that I have installed, that had been updated when yarn was installed, and it's now working.